# Datetime help in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

Please help me for this. 
I have a data like below. 
Now I want to show the employees who are in store based on the dataetime given. 
Here the emp came on 9am and left at 11 am.And again he cam on 12.30 pm and left at 19 pm . I gave datatime as `2014-05-15 09:15:45`. 
For this time the 
employee is in store but I am not able to fetch the data.

But I am unable to get the data. 
Please help me

```
Empno        ClockDate        ClockTime                ClockType 
1            2014-05-15       2014-05-15 09:00:00       I 
1            2014-05-15       2014-05-15 11:00:00       O 
1            2014-05-15       2014-05-15 12:30:00       I 
1            2014-05-15       2014-05-15 19:00:00       O
```

This is my query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.emp_a, 
                clock_date_1, 
                a.clock_time, 
                b.clock_time 
FROM   (SELECT MAX(clock_time) clock_time, 
               employee_no     AS emp_a, 
               clock_date      clock_date_1 
        FROM   clock_time 
        WHERE  clock_type = 'I' 
        GROUP  BY clock_type, 
                  emp_a, 
                  clock_date)a, 
       (SELECT MAX(clock_time) clock_time, 
               employee_no     AS emp_b 
        FROM   clock_time 
        WHERE  clock_type = 'O' 
        GROUP  BY clock_type, 
                  emp_b)b 
WHERE  '2014-05-23 09:15:45' BETWEEN a.clock_time AND b.clock_time 
       AND a.emp_a = b.emp_b 
       AND a.emp_a = 1
```

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: Hi Strawberry,

Consider the above table .I have data like that.
Now I need to get data for empid 1 info in the time '2014-05-23 09:15:45' .
My query has to display the emp data if he is available in the time I have given.
But according to my query inpt time hes there in store.But I am not able get the data.
Please help

Comment: I refer the OP to the comment I provided some moments ago.

Comment: Why would you have a `clock_date` field equivalent to `DATE(clock_time)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your ClockDate in the table is 2014-05-15, while the ClockDate in the where clause is 2014-05-23. According to the data above he does not appear to be in store at the time you query.

Comment: I am sorry the data in the where clause is 2014-05-15 only

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient query if you have a large dataset, but give it a spin:

```
SELECT employee_no, clock_date, clock_time AS clock_in,
    (SELECT MIN(clock_time)
     FROM clock_time
     WHERE clock_type = 'O'
     AND employee_no = c.employee_no
     AND clock_time >= c.clock_time) AS clock_out
FROM clock_time c
WHERE clock_type = 'I';
```

Once you have the data in this format, you should be able to add `WHERE` (or `HAVING`) and `GROUP BY` as necessary.

Sample table data:

```
employee_no  clock_time           clock_type  clock_date  
-----------  -------------------  ----------  ------------
          1  2014-01-01 12:00:00  I           2014-01-01  
          1  2014-01-01 12:30:00  O           2014-01-01  
          1  2014-01-01 12:40:00  I           2014-01-01  
          1  2014-01-01 13:00:00  O           2014-01-01  
          2  2014-01-01 13:20:00  I           2014-01-01  
          2  2014-01-01 14:20:00  O           2014-01-01  
          2  2014-01-01 14:40:00  I           2014-01-01  
          2  2014-01-01 14:50:00  O           2014-01-01  
          2  2014-01-02 12:00:00  I           2014-01-02  
          2  2014-01-02 12:30:00  O           2014-01-02  
          2  2014-01-03 12:40:00  I           2014-01-03  
          2  2014-01-03 13:00:00  O           2014-01-03
```

Query output:

```
employee_no  clock_date  clock_in             clock_out            
-----------  ----------  -------------------  ---------------------
          1  2014-01-01  2014-01-01 12:00:00  2014-01-01 12:30:00  
          1  2014-01-01  2014-01-01 12:40:00  2014-01-01 13:00:00  
          2  2014-01-01  2014-01-01 13:20:00  2014-01-01 14:20:00  
          2  2014-01-01  2014-01-01 14:40:00  2014-01-01 14:50:00  
          2  2014-01-02  2014-01-02 12:00:00  2014-01-02 12:30:00  
          2  2014-01-03  2014-01-03 12:40:00  2014-01-03 13:00:00
```

Note: the above logic assumes that a single employee cannot have overlapping check-ins.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a logical bug.

You have to fetch `'MAX'` date for `clock_type='I'` below the input date and `'MIN'` date for `clock_type='O'` above the input date.

**Example**:

```
set @inputDateTime := '2014-05-15 09:15:45';

SELECT DISTINCT a.emp_a, clock_date_1, a.clock_time, b.clock_time 
  FROM ( SELECT MAX(clock_time) clock_time
              , employee_no AS emp_a
              , clock_date clock_date_1 
           FROM clock_time 
          WHERE clock_type='I' 
            AND clock_time <= @dt
          GROUP BY /*clock_type,*/ emp_a, clock_date 
       ) a, 
       ( SELECT MIN(clock_time) clock_time
              , employee_no AS emp_b 
           FROM clock_time 
          WHERE clock_type='O' 
            AND clock_time >= @dt
          GROUP BY /*clock_type, */ emp_b, clock_date
       ) b 
 WHERE @inputDateTime BETWEEN a.clock_time AND b.clock_time 
   AND a.emp_a = b.emp_b 
   AND a.emp_a=1
;
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder,  I tried your query but If i gave inputDateTime :=   '2014-05-15 11:15:45' thenit is showing data.But for this time employee is not in office.Please help